# Eddy currents and diamagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

In this video showing magnetic melting of aluminum the metal piece levitates above the solenoid due to eddy currents:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i2OVqWo9s0

[image]

So aluminum behaves as a **diamagnet** being pushed out from the strong field region. However aluminum is known to be a **paramagnet** with $\chi_\mathrm{m}=2.2\times10^{-5}$.

How to resolve this contradiction? Does it mean that $\chi_\mathrm{m}$ characterizes only the bulk magnetic response, while "effective" (or observable) magnetic susceptibility of a finite metal sample will be inevitably different from $\chi_\mathrm{m}$ due to eddy currents (at lest, at $\omega\neq0$)? Is there any general recipe to take into account this extra contribution to the susceptibility?

Answer (score 1):

A static magnetic field does not create eddy currents, gives a paramagnetic response (Pauli paramagnetism) in aluminum.

Eddy currents (Lenz law) are due to AC fields. This is not diamagnetism.

Comment: So the eddy currents provide magnetization M~i omega B which is indeed different from diamagnetism. But why this extra M with imaginary susceptibility is not just a part of orbital diamagnetism?

Comment: This is not what one calls magnetization. It is not part of orbital effects. Eddy currents are not a bulk property, there is no way that one could make tables. It depends on shape and orientation of the sample, which is unstable in a liquid.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So, if I understood correctly, the contribution of eddy currents indeed changes the magnetic response of a body at finite frequencies, but it is impractical to represent it by any modifications of bulk magnetic susceptibility (although, I think, it could make sense for metamaterials).

Comment: @AlexeySokolik Eddy currents are also limited by the skin effect. As for metamaterials, the ones that I know are not conductive and cannot have eddy currents beyond the elements.